# Why do NLog configuration changes not take effect?

Tags: nlog, nlog-configuration

I tried to change NLog's configuration via:

```
LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget (name, foo);
LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add (new LoggingRule ("*", LogLevel.Trace, foo));
```

but it silently ignored my changes. However, when I tried

```
SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging (this, level);
```

it worked right away - but discarded all previous configuration. Why is that, and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleConfigurator replaces the current configuration, so you cannot use it for aggregated cases.

NLog does not detect and follow changes made to its current configuration unless you notify it via `LogManager.Configuration = new_config`. So use this instead:

```
var conf = LogManager.Configuration;
conf.AddTarget (name, foo);
conf.LoggingRules.Add (new LoggingRule ("*", LogLevel.Trace, foo));
LogManager.Configuration = conf;
```